# Replacing a row value in csv with a value from a scrape function

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, web-scraping

I have a script that opens two csv files. It scrapes the links in venues.csv for an `id` value for a beer from a webpage, then uses that `id` to find corresponding data from the beer.csv and then writes to a separate csv. One of the columns in beer.csv is rating_score. However, I want to use the rating_value that I can fetch using the scrape instead. So I want to replace the value in the rating_score of the row that is eventually written to the thirds csv with the rating_value that I can scrape from the page as it is more current.

This is my current script:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os
import time
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path: str) -> str:
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS

    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning)


df = pd.read_csv(resource_path("venues.csv"))
all_beer = pd.read_csv(resource_path("beer_full.csv"), encoding="ISO-8859-1")
fname = "menu_beers.csv"


def get_menu_beers(soup):
    global bar_beer_ids
    beers_all = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "menu-section-list"})
    for beer_group in beers_all:
        beers = beer_group.find_all("li")
        for beer in beers:
            details = beer.find("div", {"class": "beer-details"})
            a_href = details.find("a", {"class": "track-click"}).get("href")
            id_num = re.findall(r"\d+", a_href)
            beer_id = int(id_num[-1])
            bar_beer_ids.append(beer_id)
            name_ = details.find("a", {"class": "track-click"}).text
            rating_value = details.find('div', {'class': 'caps small'})['data-rating']

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    url_base = (
        "https://example.com/v/" + str(row["venue_slug"]) + "/" + str(row["venue_id"])
    )
    url = url_base + "/beers"
    bar_beer_ids = []
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        try:
            try:
                select_options = soup.find_all("select", {"class": "menu-selector"})

                if len(select_options) > 0:
                    options_list = select_options[0].find_all("option")
                    menu_ids = []
                    for option in options_list:
                        menu_ids.append(int(option["value"]))

                    menu_urls = []
                    for menu_id in menu_ids:
                        menu_url = str(url_base) + "?menu_id=" + str(menu_id)
                        menu_urls.append(menu_url)

                    for url in menu_urls:
                        res = requests.get(url, headers={"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
                        s = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
                        get_menu_beers(s)

                else:
                    get_menu_beers(soup)
            except:
                print("Error at " + str(row["venue_name"]))

            bar_beer_ids = set(bar_beer_ids)
            bar_beer_ids = list(bar_beer_ids)

            location_distance = row["distance_from_point"]

            bar_beers = all_beer.loc[all_beer["beer_id"].isin(bar_beer_ids)]
            bar_beers.insert(0, "venue_name", str(row["venue_name"]))
            bar_beers.insert(1, "location_distance", round(location_distance, 2))
            del bar_beers["beer_id"]

            bar_beers.to_csv(fname, header=False, index=False, mode="a")
            print("Fetching menu for " + str(row["venue_name"]))
        except:
            print("No menu for " + str(row["venue_name"]))
            pass

    elif response.status_code == 429:
        print("Server currently receiving too many requests. Pausing for 1 minute")
        time.sleep(60)
        print("Resuming...")
        continue
    else:
        print("Could not process " + str(row["venue_name"]))


print("\n \n \n \n \n---------- DONE ------------")
print("Saving results to csv...")
print(
    "Column headers for csv in order are: beer_id,beer_name,brewery_name,beer_style,abv,rating_score,rating_count"
)
```

I can scrape the rating_value easily with:

```
rating_value = details.find('div', {'class': 'caps small'})['data-rating']
```

I just don't know how to insert it into the  row data that is eventually written to the menu_beers.csv file

I have tried using:

```
row['rating_score'] = rating_value
```

right after where I define location_distance but this did not work either.

The column headers for beers.csv are

```
beer_id, beer_name, brewery_name,brewery_id, type_name, beer_abv, rating_score, rating_count, in_production
```

The column headers for venues.csv are

```
venue_id,venue_name,venue_slug,venue_full_address,venue_city,venue_state,venue_country,is_verified,lat,lng
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult without seeing sample data, but I assume the beer ids are unique.

Thus, I would try something along the lines of:

`all_beer.loc[all_beer['beer_id'] == beer_id, 'rating_score'] = rating_value`

That way you can set single values inside the df, while iterating through the beers.

The updated `get_menu_beers` function looks like this:

```
def get_menu_beers(soup, all_beer: pd.DataFrame):
    global bar_beer_ids
    beers_all = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "menu-section-list"})
    for beer_group in beers_all:
        beers = beer_group.find_all("li")
        for beer in beers:
            details = beer.find("div", {"class": "beer-details"})
            a_href = details.find("a", {"class": "track-click"}).get("href")
            id_num = re.findall(r"\d+", a_href)
            beer_id = int(id_num[-1])
            bar_beer_ids.append(beer_id)
            name_ = details.find("a", {"class": "track-click"}).text
            rating_value = details.find('div', {'class': 'caps small'})['data-rating']
            all_beer.loc[all_beer['beer_id'] == beer_id, 'rating_score'] = rating_value
```

An alternative could be to gather the beer_ids and the ratings in two lists, to create another df from and then merge it back to the original dataframe. Afterwards it is simple to replace one column with another.

Comment: Yes. `beer_id` is unique. I don't quite get where exactly I would be implementing this. `rating_value` is currently in the function  `get_menu_beers` so I can't reference it outside of that scope

Comment: Yeah that's where the line belongs. I will update my answer accordingly.